# JQuery 5 star rating system

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm creating a 5 star rating system with html php and jquery i dont know how to stop the stars rating when user has clicked on rating.
In my code when user click on 4 stars the alert box shows 4 stars but when the user move his mouse from stars the stars shows 0 rating.

here is my code, i'm not posting the css here

HTML :

```
<div class="rating">
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="1"></div>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="2"></div>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="3"></div>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="4"></div>
    <div class="ratings_stars" data-rating="5"></div> 
</div>
```

JQUERY :

```
$('.ratings_stars').hover(
    // Handles the mouseover
    function() {
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
    },
    // Handles the mouseout
    function() {
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');

    }
);



$('.ratings_stars').click(function() {
   $('.ratings_stars').removeClass('selected'); // Removes the selected class from all of them
   $(this).addClass('selected'); // Adds the selected class to just the one you clicked

   var rating = $(this).data('rating');
   alert(rating);
    // Get the rating from the selected star
   $('#rating').val(rating); // Set the value of the hidden rating form element
});
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing because you haven't said what you expect to happen. It could be that you want the selected rating, and the stars before it, to be highlighted.

So instead of this

```
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

you use this, similar to how you have previously.

```
$(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('selected');
```

But I would also remove the hover class so that it's obvious to the user on click

```
$(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('selected').removeClass('ratings_over');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hu8y3Lga/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--SAVE AS WHATEVAUWANNA.HTML AND TEST-->
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>Rating System jQuery Plug by Aldanis Vigo</title>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <style type='text/css' language='css'>
            .record{
                opacity: .50;
            }
            #value-display{
                position:  relative;
                top:  -5px;
                margin-left: 10px;
                color:  orange;
                font-weight:  bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span value='0' id='ratingbar'>
            <img class='record' number='1'/>
            <img class='record' number='2'/>
            <img class='record' number='3'/>
            <img class='record' number='4'/>
            <img class='record' number='5'/>
            <span id='value-display'>0 / 5</span>
        </span>         
    </body>
    <script>
        //Change these variables to your liking!!
        var iconsrc = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/Record2.png';
        var iconwidth = '20px';
        var iconheight = '20px';

        var value = $('#ratingbar').attr('value');

        $('#ratingbar img').each(function(){
            //Set the icon for each
            $(this).attr('src', iconsrc);
            $(this).attr('width', iconwidth);
            $(this).attr('height', iconheight);

            $(this).hover( function(){
                $(this).css('opacity','1');
                $(this).prevAll().css('opacity','1');           
            });

            $(this).click( function(){
                //Clear all of them
                $(this).parent().attr('value',$(this).attr('number'));
                $(this).parent().children('#value-display').html($(this).attr('number') + ' / 5');                                

                                                 //Color up to the selected ones.
                $('#ratingbar img').each( function(){
                    if($(this).attr('number') <= $(this).parent().attr('value')){
                        $(this).css('opacity','1');
                    }else{
                        $(this).css('opacity','.50');
                    }
                }); 
            });

            $(this).mouseout( function(){
                $(this).css('opacity','.50');
                $(this).prevAll().css('opacity','.50');
                //Color up to the selected ones.
                $('#ratingbar img').each( function(){
                    if($(this).attr('number') <= $(this).parent().attr('value')){
                        $(this).css('opacity','1');
                    }
                });
            });
        });     
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: It gives him a rating plugin using jQuery. If you read the code you will notice very clearly on the first line it says. name it whatever you want with an .html extension and test it. That should be pretty simple right?

Answer (score 0):

**It's too late answer but this works well for jQuery with Laravel back end**

```
<script>
     $('.rating').find(':input').on('click', function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '{{ route('saveRating') }}',
                    data: {'rating': $(this).val()},
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ @csrf_token() }}'
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response)
                    },
                })
            });
    </script>
```